# Sending email through java in gmail account having two way authentication

Tags: java, gmail, jakarta-mail

I want to make a function which can send email to any specified recipient(gmail). The problem I am facing is my authentication fails when I try to provide credentials which uses two way authentication in gmail. With account having no two way authentication it works fine. So what I have to do to make things happen with two way authentications enabled?

Following is the code which I am using to send email.

```
public static boolean sendMail(String fromMail, String fromPassword, String toMail, String message) {
        try {
            final String user = fromMail, password = fromPassword;
            Properties prop = new Properties();
            prop.setProperty("mail.smtp.host", "smtp.gmail.com");
            prop.setProperty("mail.smtp.port", "465");
            prop.setProperty("mail.smtp.auth", "true");
            prop.setProperty("mail.smtp.ssl.enable", "true");
//            prop.put("mail.debug", "true");

//            prop.setProperty("mail.smtp.socketFactory.class", "javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory");

            Session sess = Session.getDefaultInstance(prop, new Authenticator() {

                @Override
                protected javax.mail.PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
                    return new javax.mail.PasswordAuthentication(user, password);
                }
            });

//            Session sess=Session.getDefaultInstance(prop);

            sess.setDebug(true);

            Message msg = new MimeMessage(sess);

            msg.setFrom(new InternetAddress(fromMail));
            msg.setRecipient(Message.RecipientType.TO, new InternetAddress(toMail));
            msg.setText(message);
            msg.setContent(message, "text/html");


            Transport.send(msg);
            return true;
        } catch (MessagingException msgEx) {
            msgEx.printStackTrace();
            return false;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

By creating an application specific password at https://accounts.google.com/IssuedAuthSubTokens. Also check out [this youtube video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zMabEyrtPRg&t=2m13s) on application specific passwords.

Comment: I checked the links and got one application specific password and i am able to successfully login into browser. But in the code here at some place i need to have specify that password too. Because it is still giving me error after generating application specific password too.

Comment: Interesting. A while ago when I ran into this, the google smtp service gave me a 2-way auth specific error message. Did you happen to check that?

Comment: yes, i am talking about that only. i am getting that error named "javax.mail.AuthenticationFailedException: 535-5.7.1 Application-specific password required." So what to do to resolve that?

Comment: The only way I can imagine, is by creating the application specific password on the url I provided before and use that for the authenticating. You should not use the original password anymore if an application specific password is requested.

Answer (score 2):

There are two solution for this:

1. You can generate the application specific password by the link given by "friek" i.e "https://accounts.google.com/IssuedAuthSubTokens" and **use the generated application specific password in place your original password**. I have done this and its working

or

1. The reason why the Exception (javax.mail.AuthenticationFailedException: 535-5.7.1 Application-specific password required) is occurring is that you may have activated the 2-step verification of your gmail account. If you use an account in which you do not activate the 2-step verification then you can send the email by you original password. I have also tried this and its working fine.

Comment: You are right, i just created new account without 2-step authentication and it worked for me smoothly. Thanks for help !!