# Not able to send Mail in Java through SMTP server

Tags: java, jakarta-mail

When I try to send mail in **java** from my personal email like (sp@gmail.com) it is sent successfully.

But when I am using my company email(sp@example.com) it throws `Authentication failed exception`. I am using **TLS authentication** and it is successfully connected to host.

When I am manually login on my email it will always ask for **Two Step 
verification**. Even if I have disabled my two step verification and have also done the change to make it less secure, it still asks for two step verification as it is showing this message after putting my username and password:

```
2-Step Verification
Based on your organization's policy, you need to turn on 2-step verification. Contact your administrator to learn more.
Enter one of your 8-digit backup codes
```

In this situation what should I do? As this is my first task in this company, I would be so happy if you could help me. How I can solve this problem?

**My code :**

```
String to = "abc@example.com";
String user = "sp@example.com";
String pass = "1234";
Properties props = new Properties();
props.put("mail.smtp.host", "smtp.example.com");
props.put("mail.smtp.port", "587");
props.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");
props.put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable", "true"); 
Session session = Session.getInstance(props,new javax.mail.Authenticator()
{
    protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() 
    {
        return new PasswordAuthentication(user,pass);
    }
});

session.setDebug(true);

try
{
    /* Create an instance of MimeMessage, 
        it accept MIME types and headers 
        */
    MimeMessage message = new MimeMessage(session);
    message.setFrom(new InternetAddress(user));
    message.addRecipient(Message.RecipientType.TO,new InternetAddress(to));
    message.setSubject(sub);
    message.setText(msg);
    /* Transport class is used to deliver the message to the recipients */ 
    Transport.send(message);
}
catch(Exception e)
{
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

**Error message:**

```
535 5.7.3 Authentication unsuccessful javax.mail.AuthenticationFailedException at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:319) at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:169) at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:118) at javax.mail.Transport.send0(Transport.java:188) at javax.mail.Transport.send(Transport.java:118) java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPo‌​olExecutor.java:624) at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.r‌​un(TaskThread.java:6‌​1) at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

**SMTP configuration:**

```
configuration:props.put("mail.smtp.host", "smtp.oceaneering.com"); props.put("mail.smtp.port", "587"); 
props.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true"); 
props.put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable", "true");
```

Comment: It seems you have not pasted the code.

Comment: Hey Sergey,
I have pasted the code. can you please suggest me what should i do, i am getting Authentication failed exception :

Comment: 535 5.7.3 Authentication unsuccessful
javax.mail.AuthenticationFailedException
 at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:319)
 at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:169)
 at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:118)
 at javax.mail.Transport.send0(Transport.java:188)
 at javax.mail.Transport.send(Transport.java:118)
 java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
 at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
 at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)

Comment: What is the service provider?

Comment: It is recommended to update the question instead of posting the details here, in the comments section.

Comment: I am using SMTP with these configuration:props.put("mail.smtp.host", "smtp.oceaneering.com");
  props.put("mail.smtp.port", "587");
  props.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");
  props.put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable", "true");

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Sending email through java in gmail account having two way authentication](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8620935/sending-email-through-java-in-gmail-account-having-two-way-authentication). Please check it.

Comment: Related question: [JavaMail with Gmail: 535-5.7.1 Username and Password not accepted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2965251/javamail-with-gmail-535-5-7-1-username-and-password-not-accepted).

Comment: @S.Pandey? what is your mail server? Depends on your mail server configuration you may not have the TLS! Are you sure about your configurations?

Comment: What does the [JavaMail debug output](https://javaee.github.io/javamail/FAQ#debug) show?  Did you create and use an application-specific password?

Comment: Hey Ali M,   my configuration is correct,  it is using TLS. When i debug this then it is showing that host is connected but during authentication it falied and shows authentication unsuccessful message.

Comment: Hey Ali M,   my configuration is correct,  it is using TLS. When i debug this then it is showing that host is connected but during authentication it falied and shows authentication unsuccessful message.

Comment: Bill Shannon,  i debug this and it is showing that host is connected but during authentication it falied and shows authentication unsuccessful message. Even i have tried this by using application specific password but still it is showing the authentication unsuccessful message. Can you please tell me what should i enter for App selection and device selection  field during creation of app specific password, might be i am doing something wrong while creation of app specific password?

Answer (score 0):

1. First is need to turn on 2-Step Verification .(after that google script to give new option for creation  app passwords) https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/185839?
2. Next you  must to create the app passwords https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/185833?hl=en
3. Last step to replace this line  in your code
   String pass = "1234"; - with  app specific password, (it must generate on  step 2) Some like   String pass = "djd5n7hsd";

   And For future reader in may be useful to check  network and firewall setting on your system  and mail setting your ISP. To check if packet  can to reach gmail server.
   Try telnet command : telnet smtp.gmail.com 587