# How to send a draft email that I've prepared in several to several contacts in gmail one by one?

Tags: python, selenium, automation, smtp, gmail

I have prepared a draft email in Gmail that I need to send to several people but Gmail does not allow me to. The draft email has text, an image in it, and formatting.

I'd ideally want to send the draft to my list of contacts one by one just changing who it's addressed to. I can put the list of contacts in one column of excel and the name in another.

I could also just make the draft start with "Dear sir/madam" and send the same draft to my contacts without any modification.

If the body of my email was just text I guess I'd just use SMTP, but with all the formatting, and image in it I don't know what to do.

What is the easiest way to do this? Would using Selenium make sense? Anything else that's better?

Thanks

Comment: Please post code trial and error if any

Comment: Selenium would not make sense, and you would likely have a lot of difficulties automating Gmail anyways. Gmail has an API that could do this for you (send a draft), although the Python wrapper is a little confusing to get started.

Comment: Can you add them in bcc and send one mail? other email ids wont be visible to the receiver.

Comment: You might want to look at https://github.com/jeremyephron/simple-gmail/ and see if it suits your purposes. I am the author of this package.

Comment: Seems like CC or BCC would do.

Comment: @illiteratecoder  thanks, the problem was gmail blocking me if I put more than like 40 emails in the "To" section. I eventually had to turn the message into html and use the email library to send the email. The simple-gmail package didn't work, or I couldn't get it work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's what worked for me to send an email using python. I turned my email content into html and saved in a file and named it emailcontent. Then I used it in the following code:

```
    import smtplib
    from email.message import EmailMessage
    from emailcontent import emailcontent
    from config import email, password

email_list = ["user@gmail.com", "user2@yahoo.ca",
              "user3@gmx.us", "user4@u.ca"]

for useremail in email_list:
    msg = EmailMessage()
    msg['Subject'] = 'Test'
    msg['From'] = email
    msg['To'] = useremail
    msg.set_content('fallback')
    msg.add_alternative(emailcontent, subtype='html')

    with smtplib.SMTP_SSL("smtp.gmail.com", 465) as smtp:
        smtp.login(email, password)
        smtp.send_message(msg)
```

Answer (score 0):

1. You could use a JavaMail API to send email.
2. For formatting you can use the html formatting inside your code, which serves like your draft.
3. Read the contacts from a file and replace the variable in "Dear" $varName.
4. And to trigger it multiple times you could use java.util.Timer class.

Hope it helps.

Comment: if you go this route, gmail needs oauth type login... see this thread: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8620935/sending-email-through-java-in-gmail-account-having-two-way-authentication